# Python Problema com exercício

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o `isPerfect(x)` funcionar. Já tentei algumas outras opções mas não sei se o meu raciocínio lógico está errado.

> #### Perfect number
>
> A number is said to be perfect if it is equal to the sum of all its factors *(for obvious reasons the list of factors being considered does not include the number itself).  `6 = 3 + 2 + 1`, hence **6 is perfect**.)*

```py
    def getFactors(x):

    num_factors = []
    
    for i in range(1, x +1):
        if (x % i == 0):
            num_factors.append(i)

    return num_factors




    def isPrime(x):
    return len(getFactors(x)) == 2

    def isComposite(x):
    return False if isPrime(x) else True

    def isPerfect(x):
    return isPerfect(x)
    if sum(getFactors(x)) == (getFactors(x))
    else:
        return False

    def main():

    playing = True
    while playing == True:

        num_input = input('Give me a number from 1 to 10000.  Type -1 to exit. ')

        try:
            num = int(num_input)

            if (num == -1):
                playing = False
                continue

            if (num <= 0 or num > 10000):
                continue

            factors = getFactors(num)
            print("The factors of", num, "are", factors)

            if isPrime(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is prime')
            if isComposite(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is composite')
            if isPerfect(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is perfect')

        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, the input is not an int.  Please try again.')
            
#This will automatically run the main function in your program
#Don't change this
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOpt. Sua pergunta está meio vaga, qual parte não está dando certo? Você pode editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais informações.

Answer (score 2):

Tem 2 probleminhas básicos na sua lógica:

1. A sua função `getFactors(x)` percorre o intervalo `[1, x]`. O que funciona bem pra sua implementação de primos, embora percorra mais elementos do que é realmente necessário. Porém, você está reutilizando essa função pra ver se o número é `Perfect`, o que nunca vai calcular certo, pois o própio número deve ser excluído, conforme a definição que você colocou no enunciado: `(for obvious reasons the list of factors being considered does not include the number itself)`.
2. A função que checa se é `Perfect` tá mal feita: além de entrar em loop infinito, falta `:` após o `if` e o comando que seria executado caso a condição fosse verdadeira. E essa condição nunca será verdadeira pois você está comparando um inteiro com uma lista.

Tendo em mente o que eu apontei acima, você poderia reescrever a função assim:

```
def isPerfect(x):
    return sum(getFactors(x)) == x * 2
```

Observe a execução pra `x = 6`: `getFactors(6) = [1, 2, 3, 6]`. `sum([1, 2, 3, 6]) = 12` (Porque você inseriu o próprio número na lista de fatores).

Pra resolver isso, basta comparar com o dobro do número.

OBS: Você poderia reescrever `isComposite(x)`pra ficar mais legível também:

```
def isComposite(x):
    return not isPrime(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Segue as alterações que farão seu código funcionar.

Quais eram os erros?

1 - a função isPerfec ficava retornando ela mesma, quando deveria retornar True

2 - o retorno de isPerfect acontecia antes de entrar na condição if

3 - coloquei o getFactors ir até a metade. Para solucionar a questão do isPerfect não necessita passar da metade do número digitado.

```
def getFactors(x):

    num_factors = []
    max = int(x/2) + 1
    for i in range(1, max):
        if (x % i == 0):
            num_factors.append(i)
    return num_factors

def isPrime(x):
    return len(getFactors(x)) == 2

def isComposite(x):
    return False if isPrime(x) else True

def isPerfect(x):
    if sum(getFactors(x)) == ((x)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():

    playing = True

    while playing == True:

        num_input = input('Give me a number from 1 to 10000.  Type -1 to exit. ')

        try:
            num = int(num_input)

            if (num == -1):
                playing = False
                continue

            if (num <= 0 or num > 10000):
                continue

            factors = getFactors(num)
            print("The factors of", num, "are", factors)

            if isPrime(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is prime')
            if isComposite(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is composite')
            if isPerfect(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is perfect')

        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, the input is not an int.  Please try again.')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentaria da seguinte forma, pois há muita redundância nos if's algumas identações estavam erradas, pois no Python 3, identação é extremamente importante, pois se um código genuíno é um código simples e quanto menor, melhor.
Veja mais em: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/math.html

```py
def getFactors(x):
    num_factors = []
    max = int(x / 2) + 1
    for i in range(1, max):
        if x % i == 0:
            num_factors.append(i)
    return num_factors


def isPrime(x):
    return len(getFactors(x)) == 2


def isComposite(x):
    return False if isPrime(x) else True


def isPerfect(x):
    if sum(getFactors(x)) == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    playing = True

    while playing:

        num_input = input('Give me a number from 1 to 10000.  Type -1 to exit: ')

        try:
            num = int(num_input)

            if num == -1:
                playing = False
                continue

            if num <= 0 or num > 10000:
                continue

            factors = getFactors(num)
            print("The factors of", num, "are", factors)

            if isPrime(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is prime')
            if isComposite(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is composite')
            if isPerfect(num):
                print(str(num) + ' is perfect')

        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, the input is not an int.  Please try again.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```